# Is "great" used by native speakers to describe calamities any more?

Tags: word-choice, history

I know that "great" used to be used to indicate "very large" for disasters and other calamities, such as the Great Fire of London, the Great Chicago Fire and the Great War. Is it common for native speakers of English (as opposed to say, the government of Japan in using the term "Great East Japan Earthquake") to use "great" for calamities these days?

Comment: They should. But only as a way to identify the specific calamity. So, after many years pass, one would ask: "How did he die?" "In the Chicago fire" "Which one?" "The Great Chicago fire!"

Comment: In the presence of words such as awesome, catastrophic, incredible, unbelievable, viral, etc, the use of "Great" now usually means "It's a pleasant surprise."

Comment: While you should probably not read too much into the Great American Beer Fest, you might also consider also the great apes, the great whales, the Great Lakes, the Great Depression, the Great Barrier Reef, the Great Salt Lake, the Great Sand Dunes, the Great Gatsby, and Great Britain. And maybe Great Caesar’s Ghost.

Comment: @tchrist the only one of those that's a disaster or a calamity is the Great Depression, and that was in the '30s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may not be common, but it is certainly not unknown. The [Great Storm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Storm_of_1987) of 16 October 1987 is an example of fairly recent vintage. Because such calamities are rare, one would not necessarily expect many "Great" events.

> The Great Storm of 1987 occurred on the night of 15–16 October, when gale-force winds caused casualties and extensive damage on both sides of the English Channel, as a severe depression in the Bay of Biscay moved north-east, affecting the densely-populated London and Home Counties area. Forests, parks, roads and railways were littered with fallen trees, and the National Grid suffered heavy damage, leaving thousands without power. At least 22 people were killed in England and France, and a gust of 106 kn (196 km/h; 122 mph) was recorded in Gorleston, Norfolk.

[Images of the Great Storm](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1440&bih=796&q=great+storm+1987&oq=great+storm+1987&gs_l=img.1.0.0j0i24l9.453.4139.0.9148.16.13.0.0.0.0.1027.5063.2j0j2j6j0j1j1j1.13.0...0.0...1ac.1.5.img.YoV1DdtOoO4)

[And as a native speaker from Sussex who was woken up by the house gently swaying in the breeze, I can vouch that the event is indeed called *Great*.]

Comment: I flew into Gatwick Airport the morning after. None of us knew anything about it when we'd boarded the plane in Greece; looking down over Kent and Sussex was awe-inspiring, to say the least. Definitely *great* (as in very *big*, not very *enjoyable*).

Comment: Hmmm, "The Chicago Blizzard of 1967" which dumped 23" of snow on the city and surrounding region (much of it drifted up to 2nd floor windows I recall) was not apparently a calamity enough to be dubbed "Great".

Answer (score 0):

Although a previous answer suggests that “because such calamities are rare, one would not necessarily expect many *Great* events”, in some contexts such expressions proliferate.  For example, in the opening minutes of *The Vicar of Dibley* #104 [*The Window and the Weather*, with partial transcript at [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0739938/quotes), and first few minutes on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eaNimTgLJjA)] the following expressions are heard:
• The Great Storm (0:35–1:20)
• The Great Wind   〃
• The Great Snow (2:15–3:00)
• The Great Frost  〃
• The Great Freeze 〃
The conceit is that villagers have memories of numerous “Great” events, but do not all assign the same names to the same events.

Answer (score 0):

Our current economic doldrums have been referred to as the Great Recession, obviously in comparison to the economy of the 1929-1941 period, but true in its own right. (At least on the Western side of the pond it may finally be ended.)